# storing feed stream items NSObject in disk or as JSON

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, json, ipad

So I am implementing a feeds/timeline kind of app. Where basically when you open up the app initially it is going to memory and then use that data to return immediately, while in the background it is fetching the newer data from the server. The issue is that as of now I am storing the response to disk as raw JSON file. Now when I get back the new data from the server as JSON, basically I need to append/merge this JSON with the old one before saving it back to disk. This is quite a pain as I don't know how to merge the two JSON? Is it possible, if yes how?

The JSON format is as follows:

```
{
    "data": {
        "last_updated": 1342277036, 
        "stream": [
            {
                "action": {

                    }
                }, 
                "to": [


                ], 
                "from": [

                ],  
                "timestamp": 1342276421
            }, 

 {
                "action": {

                    }
                }, 
                "to": [


                ], 
                "from": [

                ],  
                "timestamp": 1342276421
            }, 

 {
                "action": {

                    }
                }, 
                "to": [


                ], 
                "from": [

                ],  
                "timestamp": 1342276421
            },
```

If this is not a good way to do it. Then is is better to save the NSObject's to disk instead of the raw JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than merging JSON objects, you should model the data with your own ObjC objects.

Looking at your JSON data, it seems your stream contains 'actions', a to/from and a time.

So you should create a class that represents that data.

Then when you download your JSON, you should parse it and create action objects from the data received.

You can then use a framework such as Core Data to handle your persistence. Core Data is an object model graph, and can be backed by a database, and you can use Core Data to query the database.

This will allow you to do things like "get all action objects since this timestamp" and "save all these new objects to the database".

Check out the [Core Data programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Core Data. The reason why I am not going with it is because the feeds will change a lot and so I don't want to store it in core data

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. Core Data is a very efficient framework that will be able to handle a feed that changes a lot.

Comment: Well core data stores the NSObject is self right? I've actually had NSObject's subclass that maps data from those JSON. What I am a bit confused is if I have 3 different feed streams, then how do I store those in core data?

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn some object oriented programming principals. You could create an abstract base class that models the fundamental aspects of your objects that each stream have in common and then create subclasses of your base class to implement the specific features of each stream. You could have separate entities in Core Data that make use of each stream specific subclass.

Comment: can you give an alternative on how to append the JSON if I want to take that route?